I don't know why my laptop always wake up automatically in 1 minute with windows 11
first I checked powercfg /lastwake and it showed 0
, and then I checked powercfg /devicequery wake_armed it showed None because I just disabled the mouse and keyboard to wake up my system.
And then I also checked powershell with Get-ScheduledTask | where {$_.settings.waketorun}, all the shown options are Disabled
And I also changed my system sleep model to S3 (Is that what it's called?) using the code  reg add HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power /v PlatformAoAcOverride /t REG_DWORD /d 0 but it can't help.
When I checked the system Event Viewer, it showed some information, But the Kernel-Power still shows that my system woke up because of the Input Mouse. And, before the Kernel-Power there always have 2 information from Netwtw10, which showed: 7025 - Dump after return from D3 before cmd  and  7026 - Dump after return from D3 after cmd.
Did I do something wrong?  I really have no idea why my laptop always woke up after 1 min and every time, I must shut down to avoid this, is there anyone could help me please :)
